# How does cache accessing work with two arrays being accessed concurrently within an iteration of a loop?

Tags: c, cpu-cache

A computer organization question that I have trouble grasping. If I have a computer that has a cache that have these characteristics: Direct mapping, write-through, and write allocate, and say for instance, I am accessing two arrays through assignment with stride-1, how does the cache handle both arrays when writing to the block?

```
int N = 10000;
int X[N];
int Y[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    X[i] = Y[i];
}
```

For instance, in the first iteration of the loop, when X is accessed (cold miss),  and then Y, will Y map to the next set within the cache? Or will Y map to the same set until it is full? Or is there another explanation?

Comment: It depends on the memory address of X and Y

Comment: ".... will Y map to the next set within the cache?" The cache is described as "Direct mapping", not as "n-way set associative"

Comment: My apologies, in direct mapping there is only one line/block per set. I meant will it map to the next line/block.

Comment: What do you mean by “next set”? Do you mean `Y[i]` maps to the next cache set after the set used for the previous access in Y (the `Y[i]` from the previous iteration)? Or the next cache set after the one you were just writing about, the one used for `X[i]`? You may need to back up in studying caches. The cache sets the various `X[i]` and `Y[i]` map to are determined by the start addresses of `X` and `Y`, and there will be several `X[i]` in a set, so the loop will not go immediately from set to set; it will spend several iterations using one set for `X[i]` and one for `Y[i]` before proceeding.

Comment: There are different types of cache implementations so more information will be needed to come up with an answer. One way to determine where in the cache some data will be placed is to use the some of lower bits of the physical address. Lets say you have 32 cache lines each with 16 bytes, then the cache line to be used would be determined by physical address bits [8:4]. Bits [3:0] is ignored as that is the 16 bytes in a single cache line. Bits [8:4] then selects one of the 32 cache lines. But to repeat... this is just one way of doing it...

Comment: So (again...) more detailed information about your cache system is needed. Further, we would need information about the address of `x` and `y`. Depending on the addresses it could be that you read `y[0]` into a cache line (together with `y[1]`, `y[2]`, `y[3]`,)  and then assigns `y[0]` to `x[0]` that happens to belong to the same cache line so that `y[0..3]` is replaced by `x[0..3]` in the cache. So when reading `y[1]` you will again get a cache miss. On the other hand, it can also be that `y[0]` and `x[0]` belongs to different cache lines so that they can both be in the cache at the same time

Comment: BTW: Forgot to mention that the address used for determing "cache location" can be either a physical or a virtual address. It's implementation dependant.

Comment: @SupportUkraine The question came up when I was doing an exercise assigned to me by my professor. More details include a 64-bit computer with simplified memory hierarchy, where there is a single cache with unbounded backing memory. Cache blocks are 4 words each, and the cache has 256 sets. I am trying to conceptualize/visualize how the arrays are being accessed in order to determine the number of cache misses, the cache miss rate.

Comment: Oh, and program instructions are not stored in the cache, and the arrays are indeed cache-aligned

Comment: @HenrySo For a simple VIPT (virtual indexed, physical tagged) cache system this would mean that the cache location is determined by bits [11:4] of the virtual address. (note: bits [3:0] are ignored because you have 4 words aka 16 bytes in a cache line). So if `X` and `Y` have the same value for bits[11:4] they will constantly fight for the same cache line and you'll have miss all the time. But if bits[11:4] differ they will use different cache lines all the time and you'll have: miss Y, miss X, hit Y, hit X, hit Y, hit X, hit Y, hit X repeated over and over

Comment: You can create your own answer, accept it and get (probably up) votes for it. At the least, we have an unanswered question fewer.